# Android/Kotlin - get old Activity when resume app after close

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

My problem is:

I close Activity using `finish()`, it goes to **onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy**. 
Next I open app, `onCreate()` gets old references to all views and `context`.

When I try show simple dialog it throws:

> "Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@69a156a is not
>   valid; is your activity running?"

I also cannot access text view

> progressText?.text = message

it gets old reference - i used clearFindViewByIdCache() -- but no effect.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

I try to manipulate views from DataSyncListener methods runOnUiThread

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DataSyncListener {
override fun onSuccess() {
    runOnUiThread {
        refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false // it DO NOT works after reopen app, 
        syncProgressText?.visibility = View.GONE // it DO NOT works after reopen app, 
    }
}

override fun onFailure() {
    runOnUiThread {
        refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false // it DO NOT works after reopen app, 
        syncProgressText?.visibility = View.GONE // it DO NOT works after reopen app, 
    }
}

override fun onError(message: String) {
    Logger.d(message)
    runOnUiThread {
        refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false        // it DO NOT works after reopen app
        syncProgressText?.visibility = View.GONE   // it DO NOT works after reopen app

        displayInfoAlertWithConfirm(this@MainActivity, message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->   // it DO NOT works after reopen app, throws Unable to add window
            refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = true            // it DO NOT works after reopen app
            syncProgressText?.visibility = View.VISIBLE   // it DO NOT works after reopen app
        })
    }
}

override fun onProgress(message: String) {
    runOnUiThread {
        syncProgressText?.text = message    // it DO NOT works after reopen app
    }
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener({ 
        // it DO NOT works after reopen app, 
        synchronizeData() 
        })

    synchronizeData()
    syncProgressText?.text = "test" // it works after reopen app
}

override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    actionBarDrawerToggle?.syncState()
}


fun synchronizeData() {
    refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = true

    dataSynchronizer = DataSynchronizer.getInstance(application as MyApplication?, this)
    dataSynchronizer?.startSync()                   // background featch data
    syncProgressText?.visibility = View.VISIBLE   // it DO NOT works after reopen app
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    dataSynchronizer?.stopSync()    // kill background task
    clearFindViewByIdCache() // no effect
}
```

}

**EDIT2**

**FIXED** - DataSynchronizer was not GC and hold old references

Comment: Can you put your activity codes here?

Comment: I posted it in edit

Comment: Every time you open activity once again it's different activity (different context), you rotate screen -> activity recreated (new context). DataSynchronizer should work as a Subject - every time you need to subscribe to the Subject and unsubscribe

Comment: Indeed :)  it is done on DataSynchronizer.getInstance(application as MyApplication?, this) -- 'this' is listener

and unsubscribe in dataSynchronizer?.stopSync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally fixed**. Thanks @Viktor, after checked my DataSynchronizer.getInstance(application as MyApplication?, this) I realized that DataSynchronizer was not GC -- memory leaks. So it holded old refrerences. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use syncProgressText.setText(message), syncProgressText.text expects Editable, not a String.

Comment: it is TextView not EditText